# How to get Download URL from Firebase Storage in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

The Following Code is used to Upload any image from gallery/Camera to Firebase storage. I was successful in uploading the image to storage along with meta data. Now the problem is I am not able to get the download URL of the uploaded image. Tried a lot but didn't find any solution.

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  PickedFile pickedImage;
  File imageFile;

  Future<void> _upload(String inputSource) async {
    try {
      pickedImage = await picker.getImage(
          source: inputSource == 'camera'
              ? ImageSource.camera
              : ImageSource.gallery,
          maxWidth: 1920);

      final String fileName = path.basename(pickedImage.path);
      imageFile = File(pickedImage.path);

      try {
        // Uploading the selected image with some custom meta data
        await storage.ref(fileName).putFile(
              imageFile,
              SettableMetadata(
                customMetadata: {
                  'uploaded_by': 'A bad guy',
                  'description': 'Some description...'
                },
              ),
            );

        // Refresh the UI
        setState(() {});
      } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
        print(error);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Hope You're Doing Well …
You Can Try This Method To Get The URL Of The Image(Any File) From Firebase Storage To Firebase Store And Then You Can Retrieve Image .

```
class _UploadAdState extends State<UploadAdPage> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  File _myimage;
  String imgUrl;

  Future getImage1(File chosenimage) async {
 PickedFile img =
    await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

 if (chosenimage == null) return null;

 File selected = File(img.path);
 setState(() {
  _myimage = chosenimage;
 });
}

// changing the firestore rules and deleteing if request.auth != null;
sendData() async {
// to upload the image to firebase storage
var storageimage = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(_myimage.path);
UploadTask task1 = storageimage.putFile(_myimage);

// to get the url of the image from firebase storage
imgUrl1 = await (await task1).ref.getDownloadURL();
// you can save the url as a text in you firebase store collection now
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using in my app this function. Pass image file and download with getDownloadUrl .

```
  Future <String> _uploadphotofile(mFileImage) async {
        final  Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("products");
        UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.child("product_$productId.jpg").putFile(imgfile);
    
        String url = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();
        return url;
      }
```